# How do I pass my database Connection object from my main server function to a spawned worker in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I am creating a new typeorm database connection inside my main server and also spawning a worker afterwards. How do I pass my database Connection object from my main server function to a spawned worker in nodejs? here is my code:

File: index.tx

```
async function main() {
  const conn = await createConnection({
    name: "default",
    type: "postgres",
    url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    logging: true,
    synchronize: true, // only in prod
    migrations: [path.join(__dirname, "./migrations/*.{js,ts}")],
    entities: [path.join(__dirname, "./entities/**/*{js,ts}")],
  });

    const worker = new Worker("./workers/workload_tasks")
    await spawn(worker);
  
}
main().catch((error) => {
});
```

File: workload_tasks.ts

```
let connection: Connection;

scheduleJob("worloads crong", "*/10 * * * * *", async function () {
      if (!connection) {
      // here I want to get the connection from the main.ts file and assign it  
      }    
});

expose(() => true);
```